# Jump to next paragraph in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there something like the Emacs backward-paragraph and forward-paragraph functions available in Eclipse ?

I searched in the Eclipse keys preference pane but could not find anything related to paragraph.

I know that Eclipse has more sophisticated navigation methods but I would like to make Eclipse behave (regarding key bindings) as much like Emacs as possible.

Comment: There is no next paragraph. Editors for programming languages do have commands for moving through blocks and the like.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Eclipse does not have that functionality.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> + (line number) — is the closest shortcut to what you want, that I can remember.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + (ARROW DOWN|ARROW UP) — will move you to the previous/next method

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> — will take you to the last place edited.

It’s been a while since I used Eclipse, but I believe those are all still valid commands.